# Clone checked checkbox label and append to closest div with jquery

Tags: jquery, append, clone

I'm trying to create a search filter that displays a list of values that a user has checked in a div. I want to do this by cloning the checkbox's label.

So when a user clicks a checkbox in one of these fieldsets, it should clone and append its label to the "list" div below. Here's my html:

```
<div class="filters">
<h2>Narrow by:</h2>
<fieldset>
<legend>Product</legend>
<p>
  <label for="one">Filter 1 Label</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="one">
</p>
<p>
  <label for="two">Filter 2 Label</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="two">
</p>
<p>
  <label for="three">Filter 3 Label</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="three">
</p>
</fieldset>
<div class="list"> </div>
<fieldset>
<legend>Product Version</legend>
<p>
  <label for="four">Filter 4 Label</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="four">
</p>
<p>
  <label for="five">Filter 5 Label</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="five">
</p>
<p>
  <label for="six">Filter 6 Label</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="six">
</p>
</fieldset>
<div class="list"> </div>
</div>
```

And here's my js:

```
$(document).on('click', 'fieldset input:checkbox',function(){ 
if($(this).is(':checked'))
{           
    $(this).closest('label').clone().appendTo( $(this).closest('.list'));
}
});
```

But it's not working. Here's a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/tactics/0fLnvyep/

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Label is a sibling.  Closest looks for parents.  And 'list' is not a parent.

```
//don't bind on document with delegates if you can avoid to
$('.filters').on('click', 'fieldset input:checkbox',function(){
    var $checkbox = $(this);

    if ($checkbox.is(':checked')) {
        $checkbox.parent().find('label').clone().appendTo($('.list'));
    }
});
```

That works in your fiddle, after you include jquery, but appends to all the list elements.  You could do $checkbox.closest('fieldset').next() instead of $('.list') but you should consider changing your markup so you don't have to rely on next().  Any logic that is based on positions is inherently fragile.